# Where did the API go in Magento v2.0.4?

Tags: magento2

I am looking to interact with the Magento 2.0.4 API to pragmatically create customers.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html

The above URL states that you can get an access token with the following CURL command:

`curl -X POST "http://v2.magentosite.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token"      -H "Content-Type:application/json"   -d '{"username":"admin", "password":"password"}'`

The returned result though is:

`{"message":"Request does not match any route."}`

Comment: I figured this out; I had htaccess based password authentication turned on the domain.